# Setting ContentOffset in a UIScrollView within UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionviewcell

I am working on a horizontally-scrolling UICollectionView with cells that each have a vertically-scrolling UIScrollView inside of them.

They are working great, however I would like the UIScrollViews' contentOffset to be set to (0.0, 430.0) when the view appears. Whenever I try to do this I receive the familiar "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" message.

I have tried setting this at various times in the lifecycle but to no avail. 
-When the ScrollView is configured and constrained in the Cell
-In CellForItemAtIndexPath
-In ViewDidAppear 
-I even tried grabbing the visibleCells in the ViewController's ViewDidLayoutSubviews and setting it there.

These all resulted in the same error.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: How are you accessing the particular cells?

Comment: If I access them in the ViewController (outside of CellForItemAtIndexPath) then I've only tried accessing them using the collectionView's visibleCells